# print div With unspecified background html,javascript,php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a project for kids cards where the child selects the background from specific backgrounds and write his name  and print
    But the problem is that I only want to print the card (apDiv14 with background) not the full page  Or if there was a way to convert certain content to pictures for print

```
    <div id="apDiv14">
      <div id="for1">
        <h1 ID="head1">&nbsp;<br>
        <h1 ID="head2">&nbsp;<br>
        <h1 ID="head3">&nbsp;<br>
          <br>
        </h1>
    </div>
      <div id="apDiv17"><form name="form1">

        <p>
<br>
  <input type="text" name="newtitle" size="25">
  </p>
          <input type="text" name="newtitle2" size="25">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="newtitle3" style="width: 150px;">
    <option value="">age</option>

  </select>
  <br>
        </p>
        <p>          <img src="img/BB.gif" width="80" height="45" onClick="ChangeTitle();"><img src="img/PB.gif" width="80" height="45" onClick="pri();">        </p>
        <p>
  </form>   </div></div>

    <script>
function pri() {
    window.print(); }
</script>

    function pic1(apDiv14)
{
    // background 1
document.getElementById("apDiv14").style.backgroundImage="url('img/1st card Jeddah.jpg')";
document.body.style.zIndex='4';
document.getElementById("apDiv14").style.backgroundSize = "527px 307px";
document.getElementById("apDiv14").style.backgroundRepeat='no-repeat';

}
function pic2(apDiv14)
{
//background 2
document.getElementById("apDiv14").style.backgroundImage= "url('img/2nd card Jeddah.jpg')";
document.body.style.zIndex='4';
document.getElementById("apDiv14").style.backgroundSize = "527px 307px";
document.getElementById("apDiv14").style.backgroundRepeat='no-repeat';}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [print media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) stylesheet to limit which content gets printed (by setting other content to `display: none` but most browsers are configured to not print background images (since they are rarely important and use a lot of ink).

I'd approach this by using some server side code to generate a PDF version for printing and using a form to submit the options to the server.

Answer (score 0):

javascript code:

```
  var content = document.getElementById("divcontents");
    var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
    pri.document.open();
    pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
    pri.document.close();
    pri.focus();
    pri.print();
```

html code:

```
<iframe id="ifmcontentstoprint" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute"></iframe>
```

Comment: apDiv14 in your code..content of div element you want to print.